# Motorola Barcode Scanner is having trouble communicating after computer goes to sleep

Tags: c#, scanner, barcode

I am using a DS3578 Barcode scanner and everything is great except for when the computer goes to sleep.  When the computer wakes up, the scanner is no longer able to send info to the base and there for get passed onto the software.  The light on the base stays on and everything looks normal.  No commands are sent to or from the base during the time of the sleep and awake.  However, after any scan i get 4 low red flashes that indicate a communication error.

I cannot receive any new barcode scans unless 1 of 2 solutions.

1.) i change the mode of the scan to another mode (keyboard => snapi) or vice versa.

2.) i unplug and plug back in the scanner

in both cases windows acts as if a new USB has just been plugged in and everything works.

I have tried countless things like making sure USB continues to be powered even after sleep mode, trying to create a new instance of ZebraScannerManager in c#.

I am running out of ideas to stop this from happening.  Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Upgrade BIOS/UEFI if there's a new version.

Comment: Downloading and running the updates now will check back in

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with this issue.  I was able to hook onto an event in c# that fires when windows is powered back up from there i was able to use the API to fire the _ccore open then send the device a restart command via the xml